# I2C device not available as /dev/i2c-1 (Preview 5 and 6/6.1)

Tags: android-things

Google has changed and removed the i2c device from the /dev/ path.

They add/remove the device I you are using this:

I2cDevice dev = pService.openI2cDevice("I2C1", 0x68)

And the /dev/i2c-1 is gone if you disconnect the I2C device: dev.close();

This is the reason why you do not have access via:

open("/dev/i2c-1", O_RDWR);

(this was possible in the Version 4.1 without issues)

So, now google made it complicated... and the question is, how I can bring back the device i2c-1 after boot?

Comment: What is the use case for using /dev/i2c-1? Why can you not use the Java interface?

Comment: I don't like Googles implementation. Because it's complicated and slow. I'm using direct memory access without Android Things API: 3 times faster, and the Android Things API has not all features that my solution has.

Answer (score 0):

@Kyle what you're doing may work, but it definitely isn't supported by Android Things.  When Android Things leaves developer preview, you may no longer be able to directly access device files at all (due to the device being in SELinux enforcing mode).

In the meantime, you can probably execute the following to recreate the device node.  At best this is a temporary solution, since you'll have to run these commands every boot (unless you add them to one of the init scripts).

```
$ adb shell
rpi3:/ $ su
rpi3:/ # mknod /dev/i2c-1 c 89 1
```